# Why are "\000" characters being inserted between characters of a char array?

Tags: arrays, c, char, uart

I am attempting to read an incoming stream of data from UART, and trying to add each character received to an array of `char` until characters `\r` and `\n` are received (in that order).

I have written a function (`char read_uart()`) to wait for then return when a single character is received. This function properly receives and returns the single character, as it should.

On top of this function, I have tried creating another which is supposed to read every character and add them to an array until the termination combination is received. This is it:

```c
void read_full_uart(char *message[4096])
{
    char previousTwo[2] = {'\0', '\0'};
    for (uint16_t i = 0; !(previousTwo[0] == '\r' && previousTwo[1] == '\n'); i++)
    {
        char currentValue = read_uart();
        *(message + i) = currentValue;

        previousTwo[0] = previousTwo[1];
        previousTwo[1] = currentValue;
    }
}
```

and this is how I am calling it:

```c
char message[4096];
read_full_uart(&message);
```

However, when transmitting "bitcoin" for example, this is what `message` turns out to be:

`b\000\000\000i\000\000\000t\000\000\000c\000\000\000o\000\000\000i\000\000\000n\000\000\000\r\000\000\000\n\000\000\000`

The characters are received intact, but have three `\000` characters appended to them.

I am wondering why this is happening, and how it can be adjusted so that these additional characters are not being inserted.

Comment: Your function expects to get an array of 4096 pointers to `char`. (Actually a pointer to an array of 4096 pointers to `char`) You pass an array of 4096 `char`. Also `*(message+i)=currentValue;` is same as `message[i] = currentValue;` which assigns a `char` to a `char*`. Your compiler should show some warnings for these type mismatches.

Comment: How did you manage to get `*(message + i) = currentValue;` to compile?  You are assigning a `char` (`currentValue`) to a `char*` (`*(message+i)`)

Comment: `char *message[4096]` in function signature is most likely an error. My crystal ball is quite sure you need `char message[4096]`, which is the same as `char message[]`, with corresponding change on the call site: `read_full_uart(message);`. Also, always always always compile your code with all warnings enabled (`-Wall -Wextra` in gcc) and have them as error: `-Werror`)

Comment: @Wyck probably with the famous "Implicitely making pointer from integer" warning ...

Comment: Pro-tip:  _treat warnings as errors_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here.

First, what you're passing to the function isn't what it's expecting.  `&message` has type `char (*)[4096]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of size 4096 of `char`.  The function meanwhile is expecting a `char *[4096]`, i.e. an array of size 4096 of `char *`.  This is a type mismatch.

The second is that on this line:

```
*(message + i) = currentValue;
```

Or equivalently:

```
message[i] = currentValue;
```

You're assigning a `char` to an array of type `char *`.  This is also a type mismatch.

This issues should have been picked up by the compiler as warnings.  If not, turn up the warning level by passing the options `-Wall -Wextra` (assuming gcc) and treat warnings as errors.

You can fix these errors by changing the function to take an array of `char`:

```
void read_full_uart(char message[4096])
```

Or equivalently:

```
void read_full_uart(char *message)
```

And by passing the array directly to the function:

```
read_full_uart(message);
```